# keeping track of pages and mysql_num_rows

Tags: php

Working off my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035131/printing-an-document-with-php-that-has-multiple-pages) I'm trying to figure out how to achieve what I'm after.
I have an order that gets made. When the time comes to print that order, if the order has more than 25 lines/rows i need to put up from line 26 and create a new page. My question is how would I write that? I was thinking with `mysql_num_rows` but how can I track that?

How would I break it down, say put rows 0-24 into `array1` then put `rows` 25-49 into `array2` and so on? Then put the different arrays into `while` loops?

Maybe put everything into an array, then split it up?

Here's what I have right now

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['CheckBox'])){
    $CB = $_POST['CheckBox'];
    } else {echo 'Nothing Marked'; die;}
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    @media print{ @page{margin: 5%;} }
    body{
        background-color: #CCC;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
    #MainWrapper{
        margin:0 auto;
        width:675px;
        height:900px;
        background-color:#3CF;
        position:relative;
        }

    #OrderInfo{
        width:200px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#6C6;
        float:left;
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size:9px;
    }
    #OrderInfoNotes{
        width:475px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#6C6;
        float:right;
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size:9px;
    }
    #LineHeader{
        width:675px;
        background-color:#C90;
        float:left;
    }
    .OrderLines{
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size:9px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    .PBA{page-break-after: auto;}
    .bigbold{ font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;}
    .bigger{font-size:14px;}

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    foreach ( $CB as $thekey => $Order_ID )
    {
$queryOrderHead = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Order_ID = ".mysql_real_escape_string($Order_ID)."";
$queryOrderLines = "SELECT * FROM Order_LineDetails WHERE Order_LineDetails.Order_ID = ".mysql_real_escape_string($Order_ID)."";
    //////////////////////////////////////////
        if ($queryRunHead = mysql_query($queryOrderHead)){
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    // THIS IS THE HEADER OF THE ORDER ///////
    //////////////////////////////////////////
        while ($info_HEAD = mysql_fetch_array($queryRunHead))       
        {
        $OrderDate_HEAD = $info_HEAD['OrderDate'];
        $shippingservice_HEAD = $info_HEAD['shippingservice'];
        $OrderNotes_HEAD = $info_HEAD['OrderNotes'];
    ?>                          
    <div id="MainWrapper">                      
    <!--START ORDERINFO INTO -->
        <div id="OrderInfo">
    Order ID:<span class="bigbold"><?php echo  ' '.$Order_ID; ?></span><br>
    <?php echo 'SHIPPER: <span class="bigbold">'.$shippingservice_HEAD.'</span>'; ?><br>
    <?php echo 'ORDER DATE: '.$OrderDate_HEAD; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="OrderInfoNotes">
    <?php echo 'NOTES: '.$OrderNotes_HEAD; ?></div>
    <!--END ORDERINFO INTO -->
    <hr><br>
        <div id="LineHeader">
    <table class="OrderLines">
    <tr class="bigbold">
        <td width="300"><u>Product Name:</u></td>
        <td width="90"><u>UPC Code:</u></td>
        <td width="50" align="right"><u>PID:</u></td>
        <td width="75" align="right"><u>QTY:</u></td> 
        <td width="160" align="right"><u>Packer:</u></td>    
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    // THIS IS THE ORDER LINES //////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////
            $queryRunLines = mysql_query($queryOrderLines);

            while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($queryRunLines))   
            {
                $ProductName_LINE = $info['ProductName'];
                $qty_LINE = $info['qty'];
                $Product_ID_LINE = $info['Product_ID'];
                $UPC_LINE = $info['UPC'];
    ?>                          
    <tr class="bigger">
        <td><?php echo $ProductName_LINE; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $UPC_LINE; ?></td>
        <td align="right"><?php echo $Product_ID_LINE; ?></td>
        <td align="right"><?php echo $qty_LINE; ?></td>    
        <td></td>    
    </tr><tr>
        <td colspan="5"><hr></td></tr>
    <?php                           
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // END OF ORDER LINES /////////////////////////////////////     
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                $numRows = 0;   
                $numRows = mysql_num_rows($queryRunLines);
                echo 'Total Rows ('.$numRows.')'
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ?><tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="center">--- :END: ---</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p class="PBA"/>


    <?php                       
    } else {
    echo mysql_error();         
    }
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Maybe the SQL `LIMIT` clause is interesting for you.

Comment: I don't think that would work, I want to SELECT *.

Comment: `LIMIT` works with `SELECT` ;)

Comment: Yeah you could use LIMIT start#, end# after your first sql query store the last row in a temporary variable and use the variable in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your previous question, it appears you want to print the HTML page, not use pagination. Just use a counter variable:

```
$i = 0;
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($queryRunLines))   
{
    $ProductName_LINE = $info['ProductName'];
    $qty_LINE = $info['qty'];
    $Product_ID_LINE = $info['Product_ID'];
    $UPC_LINE = $info['UPC'];

    if (!($i % 25)) {
        // echo page break every 25 lines
    }

    // output

    $i++;
}
```

Also take a look at CSS attributes **page-break-before/page-break-after**. I would also suggest using an HTML to PDF converter. They are easy to use and will make your printed documents consistent across different systems.

Comment: After fiddling around a bit I got it to do what I wanted. It was much more simpler that I would have guessed! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called pagination.

One of the way to do it is, use LIMIT clause in your query.

I would have put up here but there are hundreds of tutorials for  pagination in google with good explanation. It would be better if you search by "php pagination" and learn step by step.

Comment: Pagination is not right for this. I can't have links to the next pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can limit the number of rows returned by your query,

add LIMIT 0, 24 at the end of your query, you will get the first 25 rows.

you can have more details [here](http://www.phpsimplicity.com/tips.php?id=1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to store how many rows you want to display and another one to store the current rows being retrieved.

Look up pagination which will give you a better idea. It may not be exactly what you what but will teach you how to limit sql results they way you want.